# Download to relative folder in setup.py script

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I'm trying to download a binary file from the setup.py script (with urllib.urlretrieve).

I want to have the target path be in ./bin (bin folder relative to setup.py directory).

When doing pip install, then the binary file goes to a temp folder that gets deleted at the end.

How can I solve this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just make the binary file/folder part of the package itself?

Comment: OS-dependent, multiple possible binaries, large files (rather have them in Object Storage)